# iPhone and iTunes Match

Tags: itunes, icloud, music, itunes-match, playlist

I have a quite large library of songs and I do like the majority of them on my iPhone (main reason I purchased the 64Gb version).

Problem is that we have very slow internet here and turning on iTunes Match on my phone and telling it to download all songs in my main play list can take days up to weeks to complete.

I would turn iTunes Match off just on my phone but I like to see my entire library and download a single new song when I add one to my pc. Is there a way I can do an old fashioned sync of 1 playlist and then turn iTunes Match on without the phone first deleting all the previous wired synced songs?

Just to save redownloading them all from iCloud really.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off iTunes Match on the iPhone and synch your playlists/songs via iTunes. After synchronisation turn iTunes Match back on. You will receive a warning message, but your synchroniszed songs will **stay** on the phone (you can easily verify that by checking the cloud icon, which should not be there).

The only important thing is, that the songs you've synchronize **must** be part of your iTunes Match library. Else they will vansih after re-enabling iTunes Match.

For me that works perfectly fine.